# How to place a 3D object at the corner of the canvas such that it doesn't change it's position wrt camera?

Tags: c++, graphics, 3d

I am trying to a place a plane at the corner of my canvas(my app is in C++). My approach was to invert the camera projection matrix and then multiply it with the `w` and translate it to top right.
So it looks like -

```
  origin(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0f);
  projViewInverse = Camera.projViewMatrix().inverse();
  projectionMatrix = Camera.projViewMatrix();
  projectedOrigin = projectionMatrix * origin;
  topRight(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.f);
  scaleFactor = 1.0/projectedOrigin.z();
  scale(scaleFactor,scaleFactor,scaleFactor);
  finalMatrix = projViewInverse * Scaling(w) * Translation(topRight);
```

Is something wrong with this approach? Basically I am trying to get a orthographic projection from the projection matrix by multiplying the inverse with the perspective divide

Comment: You cannot expect to drop such a big wall of text and expect us to read through it all and debug it.

err... sorry, I think I meant Minimal Repro Code ? ;-)

Comment: Sorry, I thought this is a standard problem. I will post more code

Comment: Why do use the regular (world, view, projection) model and simply add a (-0.5, -0.5, 0) at the very end, after projection ?

Comment: My canvas is such that the top right falls there. You can ignore the translation component. Its the camera projection view matrix and not the normal matrix.

Comment: Maybe a diagram would help, I read this as if you want an oriented camera view in the top right corner, say to render a mini-view or map in a corner

Comment: Its simple really. imagine a Plane at world origin facing the +z axis. Now I only need to place it on the top right corner such that it remains there when I move my camera or change its field of view. Basically treat the 3D object as a 2D object. Multiplying it the inverse of camera projection means whenever i try to move my camera, I want to undo it for this object. Still want the diagram?